# how to check if variable exists in angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Here is my example:

```
      <li class="list-group-item" *ngIf="request.answer.user">
         <a href="" class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
           <span class="icofont-law-order icofont-2x"></span>
           <p>user</p>
         </a>
      </li>
```

I want to show the li only if the variables exists. In some cases, there is no answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you go for `*ngIf="true ? something : somethingElse"` it is pretty obvious that the `something` will always execute, no matter what (because `true` is always evaluated to true...)

In your case, you can use the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to make sure the objects exist before accessing properties on them. Your `ngIf` could look something like this:

```html
 <li class="list-group-item" *ngIf="pedido?.RecursoTerceiraInstancia?.Resposta">
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, there's a data type exactly for the purpose of checking if "variable exists": `undefined`.

So you can do this:
`typeof pedido.RecursoTerceiraInstancia.Resposta !== 'undefined'`

Answer (score 0):

The quick way

```
<li class="list-group-item" *ngIf="pedido.RecursoTerceiraInstancia.Resposta">
         <a href="" class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
           <span class="icofont-law-order icofont-2x"></span>
           <p>Resposta Definitiva</p>
         </a>
</li>
```